# How the Lagrangian function is obtained?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, lagrange-multiplier, duality-theorems

In my work which is related to user association with cellphone towers, I had the following optimization problem: [image: Image of optimization problem]

and the Lagrangian function of this optimization problem is given as [image: Image of Lagrangian function of the optimization problem]

Also $\mu_{ij} = \text{log}\frac{r_{ij}}{P_i}$ and there are two expressions for $r_{ij}$ depending on value of $i$ and those are: [image: r_ij expression when i = 1] and [image: r_ij expression for other values of i].

Also the expression of $P_i$ is [image: expression of P_i]

My query is how the eq (13) is obtained from eq (8-12). Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Are you familiar with the generic Lagrangian construction which is presented for example in the Boyd and Vandenberghe Convex Optimization textbook?

Comment: Thank you sir for your response...I know that prof. Boyd had lot of work in convex Optimization...but I don't know this textbook..

Comment: Sir, I had checked that book where in chapter 5 Lagrangian concept is mentioned. However it is for minimization of the objective function and in my case it is maximization of the objective function.....So, I think directly that concept cannot be applied in my case...I will have to change some sign....

Comment: Got it sir....for maximization I will have to change the sign to minus.....